# Python - Django add multiple urlpatterns for multiple views of template

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, url-pattern

I'm very very new to Python 3 and Django and I get to the following problem: I use a standard Template and now how to set it up when there is 1 view. But I don't get the code right for multiple views. I currently run the page locally

At the moment I have tried to change different orders within urlpatterns, and they do work when only 1 url in in there, but I can't get the second one in

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render_to_response('index.html')

def store(request):
    return render_to_response('store.html')
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from myapp import views as views
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns



urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^store/$', views.store, name='store'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls)
]
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

I would like the url pattern that lets me go to the index view and the store view

EDIT:
Full code is shared via: https://github.com/lotwij/DjangoTemplate

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. Your URL patterns look OK - you should be able to access the index view on `http://localhost:8000/` and the store view on `http://localhost:8000/store/`. A common mistake is to use `url(r'^', ...)` (without the $), and then it matches `/` and `/store/`, but that's not an issue here.

Comment: Note that `render_to_response` is obsolete - use `render` instead, e.g. `return render(request, 'index.html')`.

Comment: what do you see when you navigate to: http://localhost:8000/store/ ?

Comment: @ Alasdair I edit the render_to_response thank you :)
@Walucas I get the following error page:
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/store.html
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^$ [name='index']
^store/$ [name='store']
^admin/
^static\/(?P<path>.*)$
The current path, store.html, didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

Comment: That's why I was thinking it's in the urlspattern, like some kind of order mistake.. but maybe I'm wrong..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in the comments shows you are going to `http:/127.0.0.1:8000/store.html`, but your URL pattern `url(r'^store/$', ...)` does not include the `.html`, so you should go to `http:/127.0.0.1:8000/store/`.

The Django URL system uncouples the URL from the name of the template (sometimes the view doesn't even render a template!). You could change the regex to `r'^store.html$` if you really want `.html` in the URL, but I find the URL without the extension is cleaner.

Comment: I do wonder, I can I get to the code where I can just get to every view? I now tried this:
```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^store.html/$', views.store, name='store'),
    url(r'^products.html/$', views.products, name='products'),``` and now its pasting everything together and gives an error: "The current path, store.html/products.html, didn't match any of these." Which makes sense as this isn't a path..

Comment: It sounds like you are clicking a link `<a href="products.html">`, which is missing a slash at the beginning. It should be `<a href="/products.html">`, or even better [reverse the URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) with `<a href="{% url 'products' %}">`

Comment: I would suggest you use URLs like `/store/` or `store.html`. URLs like `/store.html/` with both an extension and a trailing slash look very unusual.